# find controller that loads particular phtml file

Tags: template, controllers

im new to this, where can i find the php controller code that loads the following template file in:

```
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: i also found out about php debug_backtrace function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers do not load templates.
Controllers load layout handles that contain blocks that are rendered by template.
The xml section you posted means is located in the layout handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable`.
this layout handle is loaded by
`Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View::initProductLayout()` that is called by  `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View::prepareAndRender()` that is called by `Mage_Catalog_ProductController::viewAction()`,
but only when viewing a configurable product.
So the controller you are looking for is `Mage_Catalog_ProductController`.